# Can't find AddHandler in reactive-banana

Tags: haskell, frp, reactive-banana

I am trying out the examples of reactive-banana in [its tutorial](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FRP_explanation_using_reactive-banana#Making_the_example_runnable). When I tried to load the example into `ghci`, I got an error.

```
Could not find module `Reactive.Banana.Frameworks.AddHandler'
```

Running it with `ghci -v` gives the output at the bottom. I installed `wx-2.8` and `wxWidgets-0.13.1.3` on ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

When I looked at my cabal directory, the `AddHandler` file is indeed not there:

```
$ ls lib/reactive-banana-0.8.0.0/ghc-7.6.3/Reactive/Banana/
Combinators.hi  Frameworks.hi  Model.hi  Prim.hi    Types.hi
Experimental    Internal       Prim      Switch.hi
```

Could someone tell me what went wrong, and how do I fix the error please?

Thanks,

Error message:

```
~$ ghci teste.hs -v
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 7.6.3, stage 2 booted by GHC version 7.6.3
Using binary package database: /usr/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/package.cache
Using binary package database: /home/ting/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.6.3/package.conf.d/package.cache
hiding package wxdirect-0.13.1.3 to avoid conflict with later version wxdirect-0.90.1.1
wired-in package ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.3.0.0-d5221a8c8a269b66ab9a07bdc23317dd
...
wired-in package dph-seq not found.
wired-in package dph-par not found.
Hsc static flags: -static
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
*** gcc:
'/usr/bin/gcc' '-fno-stack-protector' '-Wl,--hash-size=31' '-Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads' '-L/usr/lib/ghc/integer-gmp-0.5.0.0' '--print-file-name' 'libgmp.so'
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
*** Chasing dependencies:
Chasing modules from: 
Stable obj: []
Stable BCO: []
unload: retaining objs []
unload: retaining bcos []
Ready for upsweep []
Upsweep completely successful.
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting: 
*** Chasing dependencies:
Chasing modules from: *teste.hs

teste.hs:7:8:
    Could not find module `Reactive.Banana.Frameworks.AddHandler'
    Locations searched:
      Reactive/Banana/Frameworks/AddHandler.hs
      Reactive/Banana/Frameworks/AddHandler.lhs
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: The module was renamed to [`Control.Event.Handler`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-0.8.0.0/docs/Control-Event-Handler.html#v:newAddHandler) in reactive-banana 0.8. A recent update to the example at the Wiki overlooked that change.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working through that tutorial and wrote a [fixed version of the example:](https://github.com/madjestic/reactive-banana/blob/master/reactive-banana/doc/examples/Octave.hs)  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `import Reactive.Banana.Frameworks.AddHandler` line. I think it has been moved to somewhere else and doesn't require explicit import.